# Step in Butterfly Lemma by Zassenhaus - 1971: Allan Clark: Elements of Abstract Algebra

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> **Theorem.** (Zassenhaus) If $A$ and $C$ are subgroups of a group $G$ and if $B$ and $D$ are normal subgroups of $A$ and $C$, respectively, then there are isomorphisms
> $$
> \frac{B\left(A \cap C\right)}{B\left(A \cap D\right)} \cong \frac{A \cap C}{\left(A \cap D\right)\left(B \cap C\right)} \cong \frac{D\left(A \cap C\right)}{D\left(B \cap C\right)} .
> $$

*Proof.* (...)
Exercise 350 states that if $X, Y$, and $Z$ are subgroups of a group and $Y \subset X$, then $X \cap Y Z=Y(X \cap Z)$. This implies:
(i)
$$
\color{red}{B\left(A \cap D\right)\left(A \cap C\right)=B\left(A \cap C\right)}
$$
$$
\text { (take } \left.X=A, Y=A \cap D, Z=C\right) \text {; }
$$
(2)
$$
\begin{aligned}
& A \cap C \cap B\left(A \cap D\right)=\left(A \cap D\right)\left(B \cap C\right) ; \\
& \left(\text { take } X=A \cap C, Y=A \cap D, Z=B\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$

The proof is now complete.

---

**My question:**
How does he get:
$$
\color{red}{B\left(A \cap D\right)\left(A \cap C\right)=B\left(A \cap C\right)}
$$
because all I get is by plugging in as he says
$$
A \cap (A \cap D)C=(A \cap D)(A \cap C).
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $D\leq C$, you have $C\leq(A\cap D)C\leq DC=C$. So
$$A\cap(A\cap D)C = A\cap C.$$

Thus, $A\cap C = (A\cap D)(A\cap C)$, from your calculations.

Multiplying both sides on the left by $B$ we get
$$B(A\cap C) = B(A\cap D)(A\cap C),$$
which is the equality you want.